# Can TABLE(QSYS2.GET_JOB_INFO('*')) be accessed interactively?

Tags: ibm-midrange, db2-400

Reading through an article about DB2 enhancements, I was wondering why

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(QSYS2.GET_JOB_INFO('*'))
```

cannot be run from Interactive SQL

[This is the IT Jungle Article](https://www.itjungle.com/2014/12/03/fhg120314-story02/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got further with:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(QSYS2.GET_JOB_INFO('*')) a
```

Am now getting"Query cannot be run.  See lower level messages." which say "Not authorized to retrieve job information."

Comment: SELECT * FROM TABLE(QSYS2.JOBLOG_INFO('*')) a seems to work fine interactively.

Comment: It can't be run (by you) because you're running under a user profile that doesn't enough authority to what you're requesting.

Comment: Yes. You are correct, once I got authority granted the command ran ok.